# How do I use a function from one lisp file to solve for something in another lisp file?

Tags: function, emacs, common-lisp

I'm new to lisp and my professor gave some .lisp files to play around with.

http://pastebin.com/eDPUmTa1 (search functions)

http://pastebin.com/xuxgeeaM (water jug problem saved as waterjug.lisp)

The problem is I don't know how to implement running functions from one file to solve problems from another. The most I've done is compiled functions from one file and played around with it in the terminal. I'm not sure how to load 2 files in this IDE as well as how I should run the function. I'm trying, for example, to run the breadth-first-search function to solve the problem to no avail.

I'm currently using emacs as the text editor SBCL as the common lisp implementation along with quicklisp and slime.

Comment: https://github.com/n-critser/GetALisp/tree/master/whIa/sector0100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each file is in its own buffer, say `f1.lisp` and `f2.lisp`, then you only have to call `slime-compile-and-load-file` when you are in each buffer. This is bound by default to <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>. You have to compile the first file first, because it contains definitions for the second one.

But, your second file (`f2.lisp`) has two problems: search for `(break` and `(bread` and remove those strings. Check if the forms around them have their parenthesis well balanced.

Take care of warning messages and errors while compiling your file.
Then, if you want to evaluate something directly from the buffer, put your cursor (the point) after the form you want to evaluate, and type <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> (imagine the cursor is represented by `%` below):

```
(dump-5 (start-state *water-jug*))%
```

This will print the result in the minibuffer, in your case something like `#<JUG-STATE {1004B61A63}>`, which represents an instance of the `JUG-STATE` class. Keep a window open to the REPL buffer in case the functions write something to standard output (this is the case with the `(describe ...)` expression below).

If instead you do <kbd>C-c I</kbd>, this will ask you which expression you want to inspect, already filled with the form before the point. When you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, the *inspector* buffer will show up:

```
#<JUG-STATE {1004BD8F53}>
--------------------
Class: #<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::JUG-STATE>
--------------------
 Group slots by inheritance [ ]
 Sort slots alphabetically  [X]

All Slots:
[ ]  FIVE = 0
[ ]  TWO  = 2

[set value]  [make unbound]
```

Read http://www.cliki.net/slime-howto.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and detailed explanation. Both files are written by my professor. I assumed it's supposed to be 'break' instead of 'bread' but you're saying it's not even supposed to be there? Also a quick question about solving the problem itself. I can't just solve the problem by using the function breadth-search-first right? I would have to write a new function (e.g. solveWaterJug) which includes the bfs function to solve it?

Comment: @trungnt Mistakes happen, even for professors. I think it should not be there because there are compile errors and because visually this is odd. I think your professor forgot to remove a break statement, which is used for debugging. As for the problem in itself, you have to provide the solver function (don't use camelCase, write `solve-water-jug`) based on the auxiliary functions written by your professor. First, be sure to read them and understand what they do. Test exhaustively.